# How can i crop a circle from an image and over-lay it on top of another image?

Tags: macos, mac

Is there any tool on MacOSX which will let me crop a circle from an image and over-lay it on top of another image? I would like to create and an image like this:

[image: pic1]

Answer (score 1):

Any iWork App (Pages, Numbers, Keynote) can do that, its a mask, you could make it in any shape. ($79 at Apple Store)

If you are looking for a open source solution, you can try [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) or The [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/), with learning a little more, you can do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Photoshop or Fireworks to easily do this by selecting on the Magic Wand tool and highlighting the circle > Edit > Copy then paste on your new image into a new layer.

If you dont have any Adobe products you could do the same with Pixelmator or Gimp